# Interfacing with third-party public libraries/codes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, extern

I would like to evaluate an algorithm with [an available public code](http://ptinpoly.pbworks.com/w/page/19749271/Stand-Alone%20Distribution) in my project. I have integrated the [files](https://github.com/cran/ptinpoly/tree/master/src) the algorithm needs into my project: `kodtree.h`, `kodtree.cpp`, `pinpolyhedron.h`, and `pinpolyhedron.cpp`. However, the compiler complains about the ambiguous symbols. I changed the variable names which were ambiguous to something else and the compiler compiles it with no problem. This way does not look like an elegant way of fixing the issue.

I was thinking of using `namespace` but found out that, for example, the file [`kodtree.h`](https://github.com/cran/ptinpoly/blob/master/src/kodtree.h) has several `extern`s.

- Would putting them into `namespace`s cause me trouble since they can contain `extern`?
- Could someone kindly let me know the things I should be aware of when creating namespaces for such libraries?
- Is using `namespace` the right way of doing this?
- Or is it better to create an interface class for this library and put everything, i.e., `kodtree.h`, `kodtree.cpp`, `pinpolyhedron.h`, and `pinpolyhedron.cpp`, inside that class and make them private?
- What is the recommended way of doing this?

I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: what are the ambiguous symbols? It can actuallly only happen if you are overusing `using` or you have more code that declares stuff in the global namespace

Comment: @user463035818 I removed `using` and changed the symbol `Box` in `typedef double Box` to `BOX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using namespace the right way of doing this?

Yes, but not the way you try to go about it. Libraries *should* properly namespace themselves, but sometimes they can't or won't for various reasons. It's best to leave them be, unless you intend to write a full blown wrapper around the library code.

We can always apply a little discipline and namespace *our own* code. Simply put, we can do something like this in every one of our own source files<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <some_library.h>
#include <my_other_project_header.h>

namespace ProjectName { namespace ModuleName {

// Your code here

}}
```

That way your code is nicely insulated from whatever you include. And barring any `extern "C"` things, there should be no conflicts. Whatever the library header drags in, it will not cause clashes with code you write inside your namespaces. All the while, your code can refer to project entities with at most one level of qualification (code in `Module1` can refer to `Module2::Foo`, or to `Module1::Bar` as simply `Bar`). Beyond that you can always refer to things outside your `Project` namespace by fully qualifying things or by employing using declarations.

---

1: If your compiler supports C++17, it can be the more palatable:

```
namespace ProjectName::ModuleName {

}
```